# Flutter API Response

Tags: android, api, rest, flutter, dart

Actually I'm new to this Framework and I want to Know How to handle the Different Response which we get from the API.

This is the Success Response of My API.

```
    {
        "errors": false,
        "data": {
            "success": "true",
            "result": {
                "id": 16,
                "name": "Example",
                "email": "example@gmail.com",
                "mobile": "9999999999",
                "profile_image": "profile-1613993577.jpg",
                "api_token": "b81baea1dc68ed163e16d83e53478745352a5f43a5d290e18cd",
                "type": "2",
                "tax": null,
                "delivery_charge": null,
                "max_order_qty": null,
                "min_order_amount": null,
                "max_order_amount": null,
                "lat": null,
                "lang": null,
                "token": "",
                "is_available": "1",
                "otp": "552277",
                "is_verified": "1",
                "created_at": "2021-02-22T10:42:52.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-02-22T13:52:56.000000Z"
            },
            "message": "Logged in successfully"
        },
        "status_code": 200
    }
```

This is the Error Response of my API.

```
{
    "errors": true,
    "data": {
        "message": "Password Invalid",
        "result": "Not Available or Invalid"
    },
    "status_code": 400
}
```

This is my Model Page which I have Generated using the Success Response.

```
    import 'dart:convert';
    
    ResponseModel responseModelFromJson(String str) =>
        ResponseModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));
    
    String responseModelToJson(ResponseModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());
    
// This Is the Main Model Class
    class ResponseModel {
        ResponseModel({
            this.errors,
            this.data,
            this.statusCode,
        });
    
        bool errors;
        Data data;
        int statusCode;
    
        factory ResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ResponseModel(
                errors: json["errors"],
                data: Data.fromJson(json["data"]),
                statusCode: json["status_code"],
            );
    
        Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
                "errors": errors,
                "data": data.toJson(),
                "status_code": statusCode,
            };
        }
    
//This is the Data Model  Class
    class Data {
        Data({
            this.success,
            this.result,
            this.message,
        });
    
        String success;
        Result result;
        String message;
    
        factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
                success: json["success"] == null ? null : json["success"],
                result: json["result"] == null ? null : Result.fromJson(json["result"]),
                message: json["message"] == null ? null : json["message"],
            );
    
        Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
                "success": success == null ? null : success,
                "result": result == null ? null : result.toJson(),
                "message": message == null ? null : message,
            };
        }
    
//This is the Result Model Class
    class Result {
        Result({
            this.id,
            this.name,
            this.email,
            this.mobile,
            this.profileImage,
            this.apiToken,
            this.type,
            this.tax,
            this.deliveryCharge,
            this.maxOrderQty,
            this.minOrderAmount,
            this.maxOrderAmount,
            this.lat,
            this.lang,
            this.token,
            this.isAvailable,
            this.otp,
            this.isVerified,
            this.createdAt,
            this.updatedAt,
        });
    
        int id;
        String name;
        String email;
        String mobile;
        String profileImage;
        String apiToken;
        String type;
        dynamic tax;
        dynamic deliveryCharge;
        dynamic maxOrderQty;
        dynamic minOrderAmount;
        dynamic maxOrderAmount;
        dynamic lat;
        dynamic lang;
        String token;
        String isAvailable;
        String otp;
        String isVerified;
        DateTime createdAt;
        DateTime updatedAt;
    
      factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Result(
            id: json["id"],
            name: json["name"],
            email: json["email"],
            mobile: json["mobile"],
            profileImage: json["profile_image"],
            apiToken: json["api_token"],
            type: json["type"],
            tax: json["tax"],
            deliveryCharge: json["delivery_charge"],
            maxOrderQty: json["max_order_qty"],
            minOrderAmount: json["min_order_amount"],
            maxOrderAmount: json["max_order_amount"],
            lat: json["lat"],
            lang: json["lang"],
            token: json["token"],
            isAvailable: json["is_available"],
            otp: json["otp"],
            isVerified: json["is_verified"],
            createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
            updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]),
          );
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
            "id": id,
            "name": name,
            "email": email,
            "mobile": mobile,
            "profile_image": profileImage,
            "api_token": apiToken,
            "type": type,
            "tax": tax,
            "delivery_charge": deliveryCharge,
            "max_order_qty": maxOrderQty,
            "min_order_amount": minOrderAmount,
            "max_order_amount": maxOrderAmount,
            "lat": lat,
            "lang": lang,
            "token": token,
            "is_available": isAvailable,
            "otp": otp,
            "is_verified": isVerified,
            "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
            "updated_at": updatedAt.toIso8601String(),
          };
    }
    

// This is the Request Model Class for the Email And Password I'm doing The Validation, No issue in this
    class RequestModel {
        String email;
        String password;
    
        RequestModel({
            this.email,
            this.password,
        });
    
        Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
            Map<String, dynamic> map = {
            'email': email.trim(),
            'password': password.trim(),
            };
            return map;
        }
    }
```

This is My Future Class

```
    class APIService {
        Future<ResponseModel> api(RequestModel requestModel) async {
            String url = "https://www.americancuisine.in/api/v1/login";
            print(requestModel);
            final response = await http.post(url, body: requestModel.toJson());            
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            print(response.body);
            return ResponseModel.fromJson(
                json.decode(response.body),
            );
            } else if (response.statusCode == 400 || response.statusCode == 422) {
            print(response.body);
            return ResponseModel.fromJson(
                json.decode(response.body),
            );
            // throw Exception('Error Exists!');
            } else {
            print(response);
            throw Exception('Failed to load data!');
            }
        }
    }
```

If Any one Getting The Solution Please Ping me in [linked in](https://www.linkedin.com/in/vivekajee/) or [facebook](https://www.facebook.com/Vnjvibhash/) or [Gamail](http://vnjvibhash@gmail.com)

Comment: Here everything looking fine but what is your problem? did you got any error?

Comment: Actually when I'm getting the Error Response that time It will throw Exception

Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')

Comment: I think i got the problem. I am busy right now. I will definitely help you. stay in touch. thank you.

Comment: Okey, when You will be Free Please Ping me.

Comment: Can you send the Snippet for that. because I'm new in this so Kindly help me in this.

Comment: It's not a big problem  you are parsing both error response and valid response with same model class which is not possible because both responses has different attributes to parse so, my suggestion is do not parse error response it is not necessary to parse error response or if you still want to parse it then use different modal class having same attributes as error response.

Comment: Thank you it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `APIService` class

```
final response = await http.post(url, body: requestModel.toJson());
```

problem is in the second parameter `body: requestModel.toJson()`

Now replace bellow line

```
final response = await http.post(url, body: requestModel.toJson());
```

With

```
final response = await http.post(url, body: jsonEncode(requestModel.toJson()));
```

Or

```
final response = await http.post(url, body: jsonEncode(requestModel));
```

If its work or not let me know.